# Can anyone explain frontend_model in system.xml file?

Tags: magento-1.7

Can anyone explain frontend_model in system.xml file.

                            Update Lowest Quality Price
                            button
                            productprice/adminhtml_system_config_form_button
                            22
                            1
                            1
                            1